# php not showing variable from AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to post a variable from javascript to the same php page.
Here is the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php echo 'Result is '; if (isset($_GET['testing'])) { echo $_GET['testing']; } ?>
    <?php $thisPage = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; ?>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#testing123').on('change',function () {
            var testing = "confirmed";
            $.ajax({  
                type: "GET",  
                url: "<?php echo $thisPage; ?>",  
                data: testing,
                success: function() { $('#showresult').html("success"); } 
            })
        });
      });
    </script>

    <form>
      <select id="testing123">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </form>

    <div id="showresult"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I have also tried using POST but doesn't pick up in php. Also tried having a separate php file and using include_once() and still doesn't work.

Am I missing a file to load in?

Comment: Well, do you understand that URL params have key and value? You did not pass both key and value. You can use `data: { testing: testing },`

Comment: Yep, also tried data: { testing: testing }, and still cannot get php to echo back the variable.

Comment: apart from the data send problem, why are you sure that the PHP part doesn't work? you are not showing the result in your `success` function of the call, just a static string.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you are sending a string that is not a key-value pair. You can send a string (that is what happens behind the screens anyway) but it needs to be a valid query string consisting of key - value pairs that are correctly encoded.

It is easier to send an object and let jQuery take care of the encoding:

```
    $('#testing123').on('change',function () {
        var testing = "confirmed";
        $.ajax({  
            type: "GET",  
            url: "<?php echo $thisPage; ?>",  
            data: testing,
            success: function() { $('#showresult').html("success"); } 
        })
    });
```

Would become something like:

```
    $('#testing123').on('change',function () {
        // send key - value pairs
        var testing = {'testing': "confirmed"};
        $.ajax({  
            type: "GET",  
            url: "<?php echo $thisPage; ?>",  
            data: testing,
            success: function() { $('#showresult').html("success"); } 
        })
    });
```

**Edit:** To get the results of your php script back on your page, you need to use the variable that is passed to the `success` function:

```
...
success: function(output_from_php_script) {
            $('#showresult').text(output_from_php_script); 
         }
```

Also note that posting to the original page that generated the page in an ajax call, is not very convenient: It will return you loads of html (the whole page...) that you don't need.

You'd better write a separate script to process your ajax calls and have that return (`echo` out...) only what you need.

Comment: Have updated: var testing = {'testing': "confirmed"};
Still doesn't get through to php.

Comment: @IanFraser How do you know, are you monitoring the request in the console? Note that you are not doing anything with the output of your php script, you just show a success message.

Comment: Ah now I have something working, thanks, i'll post updated code.

Comment: @IanFraser If this solves the current problem, you should probably leave it as it is and post a new question for a new problem.

Answer (score 0):

- Even when you happen to succeed with it, you won't really know whether the output was a success since the ajax request will be successful, but the outcome of your PHP might not be. This is probably not what you wanted.
- You don't need to use absolute URL, simply use `url: "page.php"`

What I would suggest you to do is to create a separate php page that only contains `<?php echo 'Result is '; if (isset($_GET['testing'])) { echo $_GET['testing']; } ?>` and the call this page using ajax.